# How to compare two columns and remove duplicates from the first one

Tags: python, pandas

Sup guys! 
I faced problem connected with removing duplicates from one column comparing to another.
There's Excel file with two columns. It's like:

| first_column | second_column |
| --- | --- |
| string 1 | string 2 |
| string 3 | string 4 |
| string 5 | string 6 |
| string 7 | string 3 |
| ... | ... |
| string N | NaN |

So some values from the first column duplicates in second column. And I want to delete these values from the first one.

I try to use `drop_duplicates(keep="last")`, but it doesn't work as well. 
I already learn how to read excel via pandas and print it, but removing duplicates bogged me down. Then I'd like to receive "clean" first column and write it to new file, but I guess I can do it by myself.
Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

file_location = r"PATH/file.xlsx"
file = pd.read_excel(file_location)
file = file.drop_duplicates(keep="last")

print(file)
```

I hope you can help me or push on the right thoughts!

Comment: What do you mean by *delete these values*. Do you want to delete the whole row?

Comment: I'd like to delete row from the first column if it has duplicate in second

Comment: So in your sample you want to delete the row `string 3  string 4`, right?

Comment: No, just row from the first column (string 3), but don't delete from the second one (string 4) as it could have duplicate in the first column. I hope you understand me, as I'm not native :)

Comment: So the row alignment is not important for you? But for other columns?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean. Could you rephrase your question please?

Comment: You want to remove `string3` from `first_column` but keep `string 4` from `second_column`, right? With Pandas you can't remove a cell, you can remove a column or a row. What is the expected output for your sample please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.loc[~df['first_column'].isin(df['second_column'].tolist())]
```